# Background image under PHP Table - the approach

Tags: php, html, css, image, background

What would be the best approach to insert a background image under a PHP generated table? I.E. the table with the php generated data will be superimposed over the background image. I am looking for a simple and straightforward approach, in principle. Thanks.

Comment: This question is seeking an opinion.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes in fact it is. I would like to know the best and most straightforward approach before losing time. It is a generic question in fact. I have not started working on the approach yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.Add class name to your table

```
<?php
echo '<table class="table1">';
echo '</table>';
?>
css
  .table1{
background-image:url('image/silver.jpg');  //replace your correct path
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;

}
```

Comment: It is working in a simple html table. I need to try it on the php generated table once I do that. I will keep you posted :-)